# How to extract ANTLR4 quoted string from CSS using C++ runtime

Tags: c++, css, antlr4

I'm using ANTLR4 and the CSS grammar from https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/css3. It's mostly working but I am running into issues when I used quoted strings in my CSS. For example, with the following CSS

```
.b1
{
  font-family: "Gill Sans", serif;
}
```

I'd like to extract "Gill Sans" and "serif", both without the quotes. When quotes are used around a string, the parser generates a `KnownTermContext` which then has a `String()` method that returns a `antlr4::tree::TerminalNode*`. That returned object's `getText()` method returns the string, including the quotes. It appears as though `String()` is only valid when the string is quoted so in theory I could manually remove the quotes in this case but that seems like it should be unnecessary when using a parser like ANTLR.

Is there a way to extract the string with quotes removed or is it up to the caller to remove the quotes in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [...] or is it up to the caller to remove the quotes in this case?

Yes, this is correct. There is no way in ANTLR to strip characters from tokens (without target specific code, that is). This can be done when traversing the parse tree in a listener or visitor.